# Scheduled task using ScheduledExecutorService ? A good idea?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need to execute some task daily. Can I use ScheduledExecutorService for this? Say a piece of code that is running always at particular interval. My doubt I am keeping CPU busy always running my code, but this code will run my actual task once in a day,week or month depends on configuration.

```
ScheduledExecutorService schedular = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
schedular.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MySchedular(), 1, 24, TimeUnit.HOUR);
```

Or do we have any better option?

Comment: The worry is not that the CPU will be busy because the process should sleep when the code is just waiting on a (month-long) timer. The bigger problem comes from the process ending (for example, machine reboot) and nothing there to restart it. Different systems have different mechanisms for such intervaled tasks, *nixs have `cron`, but I don't know about your system.

Comment: which version of Java do you use?

Comment: Which OS your using ?

Comment: if your using Linux then CronJob will be best option everything is done by cron job you just need to give path of script which want to execute....

Comment: @msw - I am using windows 7, in windows all .bat file executes on machine startup/login(if you will put it in C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup).. Windows trigger my .bat file that triggers my java code. No need to trigger manually.

Comment: what you will get with a cron job is the separation of concern i.e. the call for code execution would be taken from outside your code through the OS. By placing the execution mechanism inside the code you will have to monitor that the application is up all the time to run the scheduled task

Comment: Even in windows we have scheduler their we can call my .bat file, But it behaves wrongly in another machine(ie different version of windows.) So I was thinking about this option.

Comment: it is daily at a given hour ? or your don't care?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes daily at 10 PM. This we can handle in parameters of scheduleAtFixedRate().

Comment: Even if you keep your program running permanently in background, you will need to use the Task Scheduler to launch it automatically (e.g. after reboot), and you will need some mechanism to restart it if it stops. It seems you'd better fix that issue you have with the Task Scheduler than looking for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

For very a basic need you can indeed use a `ScheduledExecutorService` as you do, but if you want to do complex things like scheduling your task at a given hour in the day, you should consider using [**quartz-scheduler**](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start.html).

Here is how to schedule a task at 10 PM:

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MySchedular.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(22, 00))
    .build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
// and start it off
scheduler.start();
```

The same trigger created with a [**cron expression**](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) would be:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 22 00 * * ?"))
    .build();
```

Comment: What I understand from ScheduledExecutorService, JVM register its next execution time somewhere in memory and maintains it, whenever that moment comes it(JVM) execute its task and parallely updates next execution time in memory. And cycle continues until our program terminates. So it looks like CPU is busy with our program but actually it is not.

Comment: indeed `ScheduledExecutorService` won't consume much CPU, only your tasks will

Comment: However as mentioned in my answer, if you want to be able to schedule task at a fixed hour, you will need to implement the logic yourself, the `ScheduledExecutorService` is not capable of doing it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using Windows and CronJob is not available, ScheduledExecutorService is a very good choice on your part. The only problem you need to look into is what happens if for whatever reason your process terminates not due to Windows reboot. Usually critical systems have some sort of Watchdog processes that monitor your process and restart it if it was terminated. But this is probably out of scope for this question. In short the answer to your question is: ScheduledExecutorService is the correct choice.